# Retrieving KEYID from HLS Manifest

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I'm trying to retrieve the `KEYID` value from my HLS video manifest below

```
#EXT-X-SESSION-KEY:METHOD=SAMPLE-AES,URI="data:text/plain;base64,A2234527890AAAAA7e+LqXnZSs6jyCfc1R0HRoAAABgSEA9tEdoxREFwszTCHC2rRIJI88aJmwY=",KEYID=0x0F6D11DA12344170C444C21C2DAB4482,KEYFORMAT="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed",KEYFORMATVERSIONS="1"
```

I retrieved the HLS Manifest using the code below as recommended by the ExoPlayer website

```
    override fun onTimelineChanged(timeline: Timeline, reason: Int) {
        super.onTimelineChanged(timeline, reason)

        val manifest: HlsManifest? = exoPlayer.currentManifest as HlsManifest?
    }
```

My problem is that I am unable to find that `KEYID` property within that `manifest` variable.

With that said, how would I go about retrieving that property?

Answer (score 0):

After further inspection of the `manifest` variable using Android Studios debugger, I was able to find `tags` within it. It contains a list of HLS tags and within it, is `KEYID`

So I looped through the tags trying to find one with `KEYID` and then used ChatGPT (For fun :p) to write an expression for finding that tag.

This is probably not the best way to go about it, but posting it as an answer unless someone is able to come up with a better solution.

Thanks.

```
        override fun onTimelineChanged(timeline: Timeline, reason: Int) {
            super.onTimelineChanged(timeline, reason)

            val manifest: HlsManifest? = exoPlayer.currentManifest as HlsManifest?

            if (manifest != null) {
                val keyIdRegex = Regex("KEYID=([^,]+)")
                val tags = manifest.multivariantPlaylist.tags
                val keyIdMatches = tags.mapNotNull { keyIdRegex.find(it) }
                for (matchResult in keyIdMatches) {
                    val keyId = matchResult.groupValues[1]
                    println("KEYID value: $keyId")
                }
            }
        }
```